# How do you set up a many to many relationship in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8

I have set up two groups: "Commodities" and "Groups". How do you set up a many to many relationship for the two groups with Laravel 8? How do you add "Commodities" and "Groups" with "add-commodities" and "add-groups"? How do you retrieve "commoditiesbygroup" and "groupsbycommunity" from the database?

Comment: <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCommoditiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('commodities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: Migration/groups_table:

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('groups');
    }
}

Comment: Migration/commodity_group_table:


    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('commodity_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('group_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('commodity_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('commodity_id')->references('id')->on('commodities')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

Comment: Model/Commodity:

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Commodity extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "commodities";
    public function Groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class,'commodity_groups'); 
    }
}

Comment: Model/Group:

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "commodities";
    public function commodities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Commodity::class,'commodity_groups'); 
}
}

Comment: Model/CommodityGroup:

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CommodityGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "commodity_groups";
}

Comment: CommodityController:

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Commodity;
use App\Models\Group;
class CommodityController extends Controller
{
    public function addCommodity()
    {
        $commodities = [
            ["name"=>"Apple"],
            ["name"=>"Orange"],
            ["name"=>"Mango"],
            ["name"=>"Peach"],
            ["name"=>"Almond"]
        ];

Comment: ];
        Commodity::insert($commodities);
        return "Many to many relationship!";
    }
    public function addGroup()
    {
        $group = new Group();
        $group->name = "One";
        $group->save();
        
        $commodityids = [1,2,3];
        $group->commodities()->attach($commodityids);
        return "Commodity to Group relationship";
    }

Comment: public function getAllCommoditiesByGroup($id)
        {
        $Group = Group::find($id);
        $commodities = $group->commodities;
        return $commodities;
        }

        public function getAllGroupsByCommodity($id)
        {
            $commodity = Commodity::find($id);
            $groups = $commodity->groups;
            return $groups;
        }

Comment: Webroutes:
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommodityController;

Route::get('/add-commodities', [CommodityController::class, 'addCommodity']);
Route::get('/add-groups', [CommodityController::class, 'addGroup']);
Route::get('/commoditiesbygroup/{id}', [CommodityController::class, 'getAllCommoditiesByGroup']);
Route::get('/groupsbycommodity/{id}', [CommodityController::class, 'getAllGroupsByCommodity']);